# Photoshop Scripting select contents of a layer & color

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Using a javascript script in Photoshop 2022 (v 23.0.1), I am trying to change the color of a single item in one of my layers.  I can access the layer, but I cannot change the color of it's contents.

```
var document = activeDocument;
var groupA = document.layers["Group"];
var layerA = groupA.layers["Layer In Group"];
var layerB = groupA.layers["Clipping Mask for layerA"];
```

The `layerA` contains a single item which is colored white.  I'd like to change it's color.

I assume I need to select the contents of that layer, then apply a color to it. But I'm not sure this is the best way to do this.

I could also add a clipping mask for that layer, then fill that with color.  Would this be easier/better?

Ideally I'd like to change it using a hex color code, but any way I can change it would be fine.

UPDATE: I was able to solve the problem by making the layer the activeLayer in the document.

```
    // set the active layer to the layer requiring fill color
    document.activeLayer = layerB;
    // getBodyFillColor() is my method that returns the correct color
    var color = getBodyFillColor();
    // Once I set the active layer, it's automatically the selection layer??  (not sure how this works)
    document.selection.fill(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just fill with a colour:

```
// Fill colour
var myRGBCol = [255, 0, 128];  //define your colour here
var col = new SolidColor;

col.rgb.red   = myRGBCol[0];
col.rgb.green = myRGBCol[1];
col.rgb.blue  = myRGBCol[2];

var blend = ColorBlendMode.NORMAL; // Normal
var op = 100; // opacity

document.selection.fill(col, blend, op, false);
```

Comment: Right.  I think the step I was missing was setting the active layer.  
`document.activeLayer = layerB;` then I could fill the `document.selection` as you pointed out.